# Norm of a vector resulted from Orthogonal Projection

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, projection

I have a question here that I don't know how to proceed:

> $\vec{u} [3,4]$ and $\vec{v}[2,k]$ are two vectors where k belongs to real number. **Find k such that the norm of the projection of $\vec{v}$ over $\vec{u}$ equals to 1.**

What I am able to do is to find the equation for the projection $\vec{v}_\vec{u}$

- $\frac{\vec{u}\vec{v}}{\vec{u}\vec{u}}\vec{u}$
- $\frac{6+4k}{25} (3,4)$

However, I am not sure what should I do next to find the k such that the norm of the projection is 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing your work, what's the norm of $\lambda\vec{u}$ where $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$? What about the norm of $\frac{6+4k}{25}\vec{u}$?

Comment: okay so the norm of $\vec{u}$ would be 5 (the square root of 9+16). Consequently, the norm of the whole thing would be $\frac{6+4k}{5}$? Do I need to add absolute value for 6+4k? If yes, why?

Comment: By definition (specifically, by absolute homogeneity) $||\lambda\vec{u}||=|\lambda|||\vec{u}||$, so yes, absolute sign is needed in calculation. Once you get the results, a picture with these 2-D vectors will be helpful in understanding what's happening geometrically.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for helping me on this!